# Change file on multiple server using Web interface

Tags: php

Currently, I am handling around 10 servers. Where I have to maintain an environment config file on each server. Code Deployment is done by Capistrano. But I have to manually maintain these config files as it contains sensitive data, which I cannot put on GIT repository.

I am looking for a tool which can help me maintain these config files as well. So that If I have to make any configuration change, I can do with a web interface. These config files may content some configuration same on all servers and some different.

So If any one of you may have face the same issue and know a tool which can help me with this issue. It will be great help.

P.S.: These config files are PHP constants file like this.

```
<?php
class Constants
{
    public static $key = 'value';
    public static $key = "value";
    public static $key = array("HOST" => '127.0.0.1', "PORT" => 'PORT');
    public static $key = array("flag" => 1);
}
?>
```

Comment: Just make a 10 lines script that `scp`'s the file to the destination system. Using a password less key you can do that in a secure but non interactive manner. An alternative is to have a simple daemon poll for new configurations on a periodic base, maybe via https. Todays solution is to have the remote systems as virtual appliances and respawn them with changed configurations whenever required.

Comment: Use private git / bitbucket

Comment: @arkascha I have already created that script to copy. But I am looking for a tool which read the configuration from different servers, Show it to a web page and on update and submit, copy that to all servers.

Comment: That is something else than what you asked in your question... Why do you have to read a configuration file _from different systems_? And the transfer that again to different systems, after an update? From where to where? This reads like a n:m relationship, so what are the rules?